# How to free swap without rebooting (to avoid hourly alert emails)?

Tags: linux, swap

I get alert emails whenever swap usage is at 100%. In my case, swap usage doesn't reduce later on (even though memory is free) so I get an alert email every hour.

How can I reduce swap usage without rebooting my Linux server?

Comment: If your swap is regularly filling up, then you need to increase the amount of RAM in your server.

Comment: I'd rather know what process is using the swap rather than throwing more ram at it, e.g. run top(press Op).

Comment: What is your swappiness set to? `cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness` A high swappiness and small swap file means it will be full often. Reduce swappiness or increase the size of the swap file, or both.

Comment: @EEAA not necessarily. For instance the swap may be used although there is plenty of "free" memory, but the RAM is used largle for cached memory and buffers (to reproduce this I just need to make a tar file of a large disk).

Answer (score 15):

You can run `swapoff -a` as root to swap all memory back in. Don't forget to run `swapon -a` afterwards to make swap available again. Note that `swapoff` will fail if there is not enough physical memory available to swap everything back in.